# Post-build event not executing

Tags: visual-studio, build

I've written a post build script for my visual studio project

```
copy "$(TargetDir)ReportTemplates\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Excel\"
del /q "$(TargetDir)ReportTemplates"
```

and in the build output I get

```
  V:\project\ReportTemplates\CRC150.xls
  V:\project\ReportTemplates\SR558.xls
  V:\project\ReportTemplates\SR559.xls
          3 file(s) copied.
  Deleted file - V:\project\ReportTemplates\CRC150.xls
  Deleted file - V:\project\ReportTemplates\SR558.xls
  Deleted file - V:\project\ReportTemplates\SR559.xls
```

However when I got take a look in the directory the files have copied, but they are still there in the original location.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: I've figured out a way to fix it. The files were set to copy to output directory and then I was copying from the target directory. I've now changed it so that they don't copy to output and then done a post build task of copy from project

Comment: Could it be that Post-build script fires after a build but before Copy to Output Directory?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this files are readonly, try adding /f - force in post build script. Also check if this files are not opened by you`r application or excel reader because this could be reason why you can`t delete them.